# Adding up data values from different vector layers

Tags: qgis, shapefile, summarizing

I have multiple files each loaded as a layer.
Each file has just an easting northing and a count value, as below.

```
easting,northing,count
435575,804275,15
435625,804225,29
435625,804275,39
435625,804325,53
435675,804075,8
435675,804125,11
435675,804175,45
435675,804225,60
435675,804275,81
435675,804325,117
435675,804375,83
435725,804025,16
435725,804075,21
435725,804125,64
435725,804175,76
435725,804225,113
```

All the easting and northing points are on the same 50m x 50m grid.

I have used the count value to colorize this data, selecting a 50m square though the geometry manager which looks good for each layer in isolation.

What I can't work out how to do is :

These layers overlap each other. Where they overlap each other I would like to sum the count from each point at the same easting and northing position, to produce a single data set.

Answer (score 2):

1. vector > Geoprocessing Tools > intersect - gets you the overlap area
2. vector > data management tools > join attribute by location - joins your point data to the intersect layer
3. use field calculator to sum all the count attributes into a new field

Answer (score 1):

Since your layers are points dataset, *intersect* may not work. If so, please try a workflow below.

(1) Your data

[image]

I imported your sample as `points1` layer (green), and chose last 3 points of your data as the overlapping `points2` layer (orange)...[LHS] These layers can be displayed as if tiles (50m x 50m square symbols), but they are point layers... [RHS image]

(2) Add up 2 layers

[image]

There would be various approaches, but I used [refFunctions](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin this time, which provides `geomequals()` function to overlay point-point layers.

(2 - 1) Extract `count` data from `point2` layer.

1. Open attribute table of `point1` layer and create a new `count_2` field
2. Expression is `geomequals( 'points2', 'count')`

(2 - 2) Add `count` and `count_2` fields.

1. Create a new `my_sum` field
2. Expression is `"count"  + coalesce("count_2",0)`

(3) Visualize `my_sum` field

[image]